# Angular passing parameter to service

Tags: angular, service

MyService>

```
 export class MediaService {
  private matches = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
  public match$ = this.matches.asObservable();

  constructor(public readonly query: string) {
    if (window) {
      const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(this.query);
      const listener = event => this.matches.next(event.matches);
      listener(mediaQueryList);
      mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', listener);
    }
  }
}
```

FooBarComponent

```
class FooBarComponent implements OnInit {
  isDesktop: boolean;
  private mediaService = new MediaService('(min-width: 768px)');

  constructor(private mediaService:MediaService )

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mediaService.match$.subscribe(value => this.isDesktop = value);
  }
}
```

Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MediaService

It works if I call the service but do not pass any parameters, if I set the value on the service it works e.g

MediaService file

```
const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia((min-width: 768px)');
```

I've try passing the parameter using @Inject into the service:

```
constructor(@inject('query') private query: string) {}
```

FooBarComponent

```
provider: [
{provider: 'query', useValue: 'query',
]
```

But does not work!!!
reference: https://indepth.dev/posts/1383/responsive-angular

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? The docs example work perfectly https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-media-test Also, the docs example does not inject the service in the component. You are instead injecting it into the constructor.

Comment: @GusSL I'm not getting the error anymore, but the parameter value is not working when passing using the new MediaService('(min-width: 768px)'), so how can I use services instead?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does it give you an error? When changing the parameter manually e.g. to `'(min-width: 100px)'` in `FooBarComponent` it works as intended. Do you want to change the `768px` value dynamically?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with project build, I rebbot my machine and now evrething is working, I lost over 2 hours trying to udnerstand, thanks for your help!